# how to implement the functions which are defined inside the conio.h

Tags: programming, development, c, ncurses

I wanted to use the `conio.h` header file in one of my C codes but as we know the header file is not available for Ubuntu, what should we do if we want to implement the functions if the header file `conio.h`, like `getch()` & `getche()` etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `curses.h`, available [here](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/) is a `C` library for a terminal user interfaces (TUI).

`conio.h` was a `C` library for terminal user interfaces for MS-DOS systems not *nixes.

[Here](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/UnixAndC/CLanguage/Curses.pdf) is a turorial for the curses library and [here](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/doc/PDCurses.txt) is the official manual

To get the `curses.h` header type: `sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev`

Comment: If m including the header file curses.h the fatal error comes no such file or directory..

Comment: thnx @Stef;but now the problem arises, if I made an application   using this header file and wanted to run it on another machine and that machine surely will not have the curses.h header file. And again the application wont work on it.

Comment: You can compile and link statically against `curses.h` in order to produce a self contained executable but the best solution is to deploy your executable as a `.deb` package with dependencies. See [here](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html) about how to package applications.

Comment: thnx @stef I'll let you know if there is more to ask in this.:)